# Intellij shortcut directly go to any variable Class or specific implementation instance method

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-14

```
SomeClass {
   AbstractType/Interface instanceVariable = new SpecificType();

   ...

   SomeFn(){
     instanceVariable.instanceMethod();
                           | <- go to SpecificType.instanceMethod() directly
     
     instanceVariable.instanceMethod();
           | < go to SpecificType of instanceVariable directly
}
```

Looking for an Intellij shortcut to go to variable's Specific Class. To go to instanceVariable in a large code and want to go to its SpecificType class. It needs three commands, go to instanceVariable definition using Go to Declaration (F3), see its definition, move cursor to actual type `new SpecificType();`, go into it and come back where you were using (Command + [). We can also hover over "instanceVariable" definition using F2 to see what its type is, but, there is no direct shortcut to go to actual Class "SpecificType" defining this instance variable.

Same with instanceMethod(), there is "Go to Implementation" on this method of an instance (Shift+Command+I) and choose specific type whereas instance is already defined right in the class as "SpecificType" here. See method type using F2 to see which class, in this case, it will show "SpecificType" the method type belongs to, then choose the specific implementation and choose SpecificType from several drop downs.

It would be nice if there was a shortcut to directly to to exact SpecificType Class or its method instead of multiple commands.

Answer (score 1):

Why Main Menu | Navigate | **Go to Implementation(s)** action (Alt+Cmd+B default shortcut) doesn't work for you? Invoke it on the method call and from drop-down choose the implementation you are interested in:

[image]

Comment: Right, but my question was not to choose from drop down whether I choose the variable or the method. IntelliJ has enough intelligence to know what type of instanceVariable it is already right, SpecificType can be the final concrete class most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

To get declaration of `SpecificType` from `instanceVariable`:

Main Menu | Navigate | Type Declaration
On Windows: ctrl + shift + B